# WorldPop Google Earth Engine Mapping

Tags: google-earth-engine

I would like to map with palette and definition used in the example of "old" WorldPop data as in the image bellow (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/WorldPop_POP)
the "new" world wide coverage data on WorldPop (WorldPop/GP/100m/pop at: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/WorldPop_GP_100m_pop ) in Google Earth Engine

[image]

my current code does not plot as in the image attached ... but only black and white with all saturated ....

var worldPop = ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop")
                          .filterDate('2017');
Map.addLayer(worldPop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first link you provide there is a variable "populationVis" that defines the visualization parameters. Just apply that visualization to your collection.

```
var worldPop = ee.ImageCollection("WorldPop/GP/100m/pop") .filterDate('2017');
var populationVis = {
    min: 0.0,
    max: 50.0,
    palette: ['24126c', '1fff4f', 'd4ff50'],
    };

Map.setCenter(113.643, 34.769, 7);
Map.addLayer(worldPop, populationVis, 'Population');
```

Comment: How I can export to drive a clipped part of such image :

Comment: Check this https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/exporting

Comment: Export.image.toDrive({
image: dataset.select('population'),
description: 'worldPop',
scale: 100,
region: export_geometry_2
})
did not work

Comment: The image is worldPop. Regarding the region, with this command you will export the area in your canvas: Export.image.toDrive({ image: worldPop,  description: 'worldPop',  scale: 100})